# Google Place Autocomplete Removes Street Address

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

We are using the Google Place Autocomplete on our website to make the checkout process easier for our customers.  However, there are a certain percentage of addresses that end up with no street number, just the street name, city, and ZIP.  I thought this was an error on our end, but it happens on Google's demo page as well (https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/places-autocomplete-addressform).  You can see this by using this address:

10209 Aurora Sky
Schertz TX 78154

If you type in the address, you can see that it correctly offers an exact match, but when  you click on it in the list it fills in everything but the street number.

Whether it is a bug or a feature (it could be that new construction is not in their address books yet, who knows), does anyone know of a workaround?  Perhaps capturing the option they click on and then overwriting it after the autocomplete does its thing?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like that address is new and hasn't been added to google maps officially. If you search it on maps, it give just the street. You can try adding new address here https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/1096044?hl=en